# Set selected dates ad default date in Jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

When User picks Choose Date in Filter and changes start date and pushes Enter. Filter on the list is performed and data is shown. After that if user opens Choose date calendar it will still show the default days. How can I make date picker to take selected dates as a default date?? Any Suggestions? 
Here is my code:

```
if ($('.js-datepicker').length) {
                    $('.js-datepicker').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).data('datepickerAltfield')) {
                            var $altfield = $(this).find('.js-datepicker-altfield');
                            var inputName = $altfield.attr("name");
                            var defaultDate = new Date();
                            if (inputName.indexOf("fromDate") >= 0) {
                                defaultDate.setDate(defaultDate.getDate() - 7);
                            }
                            $(this).datepicker({
                                altField: $altfield,
                                showOtherMonths: true,
                                firstDay: 1,
                                dayNamesMin: [ "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" ],
                                dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
                                defaultDate: defaultDate
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).datepicker();
                        }
                    });
                }
```

I have tried onSelect method to assign selected value to some variable, but it didn't worked.

```
onSelect: function(dateStr) {
        $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', dateStr);

    }
```

Comment: can you create a demo?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you seek is the ability to set the date?

```
var datestr = "10.12.2012";
$('.js-datepicker').datepicker("setDate", datestr);
```

Example using the onSelect:

```
 ...prior datepicker options
 defaultDate: defaultDate,
 onSelect: myselect
```

function myselect as:

```
function myselect(presentdate) {
    alert(presentdate);//alerts the date selected string (as 1.15.2012 for instance)
    var datestr = "10.12.2012";//new date to set
    $('.js-datepicker').datepicker("setDate", datestr);// set date
}
```